# unable to get datetime of the clicked event - fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem of the eventClick function which I set the input type is date, it's working well and can show output in specified textbox. However I set the input type is datetime-local , it can't show datetime in specified texbox.

This is my javascript:

```
eventClick:  function(arg) {
             $('#modal_show_from > #mesyuarat_from_date').val(arg.event.extendedProps.mesyuarat_from_date);
             $('#calendarModal').modal();
            },
            
      editable: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true, 
      events: <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>
    });
```

This is show html code (for show datetime):

```
<div class="col-lg-10 padding_important"  id="modal_show_from">
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="mesyuarat_from_date" name="mesyuarat_from_date" value="" title="Tarikh Masa Mesyuarat - From">
</div>
```

Comment: You can debug the code where you can find what actual value you are passing to function. OR share the fiddle link.

Comment: I have using console.log and the value can pass, but has no show in textbox